# С# Передача данных из GUI в метод работающий асинхронно

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await

Добрый день! Прошу помощи у экспертного сообщества.

Нужен шаблон (пример кода) решающий следующую задачу:

Асинхронно выполняется некая длительная задача, промежуточные результаты которой отображаются в GUI  и при изменении некоторых контролов этой же формы новые значения попадали в запущенный асинхронно метод (выполняющиеся в потоке отличном от потока GUI).

Примеров для первой части задачи полно (отображения промежуточных результатов) а вот передача данных из GUI в метод работающий асинхронно не нашёл.

Инструменты: MS VISUAL C#, WINFORMS приложение. Для организации асинхронности исп. конструкция Async/await.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Универсального метода не существует ибо такая задача в принципе лишена смысла.

Comment: Для отображения прогресса обычно используется https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh193692(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Не вполне ясно, зачем ваш асинхронный метод бежит не в UI-потоке. Но допустим, что вам это нужно. Тогда получить данные из UI-потока можно самостоятельно, при помощи диспетчера. Пример:

```
async Task BackgroundComputation()
{
    var oldValue = "";
    while (true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        var newValue = await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => InputInfo.Text);
        if (oldValue != newValue)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(newValue);
            oldValue = newValue;
        }
    }
}
```

(запускать через `Task.Run(BackgroundComputation);`)

Здесь `InputInfo` — `TextBox`, в который юзер вводит текст. При помощи конструкции `await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => InputInfo.Text)` значение `InputInfo.Text` считывается в UI-потоке и доставляется в рабочий поток.

По поводу того, как доставлять результаты работы в UI-поток, наверное, лучше всего воспользоваться классом `Progress<T>`.

Comment: `Не вполне ясно, зачем ваш асинхронный метод бежит не в UI-потоке.` для того чтобы не зависал интерфейс...

Comment: @Ev_Hyper: Ну так просто не надо делать в нём блокирующее ожидание. Например, на `stream.Read`, а `await stream.ReadAsync`. Ну и процессор-интенсивные операции выносить в подтаск через `result = await Task.Run(() => CpuBoundCode())`.

Comment: Это очевидно :)

Comment: @Ev_Hyper: Ну вот. А если код так структурирован, то проблемы с обращением к UI-контролам или VM-объектам нет, большая, управляющая часть кода, кроме вычислений, бежит в UI-потоке.